# Generate a quasi periodic signal

Tags: python, fft, spectrum, ifft, periodicity

Is there a way to generate a quasi periodic signal (a signal with a specific frequency distribution, like a normal distribution)? In addition,
the signal should not have a stationary frequency distribution since the inverse Fourier transform of a Gaussian function is still a Gaussian function, while what I want is an oscillating signal.

I used a discrete series of Normally distributed frequencies to generate the signal, that is

[image]

The frequencies distribute like this:

[image]

So with initial phases

[image]

, I got the signal

[image]

However, the signal is like

[image]

and its FFT spectrum is like

[image].

I found that the final spectrum is only similar to a Gaussian function within a short time period since t=0 (corresponding to the left few peaks in figure[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGVhf.png) which are extremely high), and the rest of the signal only contributed to the glitches on both sides of the peak in figure[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Womgx.png).

I thought the problem may have come from the initial phases. I tried randomly distributed initial phases but it also didn't work.

So, what is the right way to generate such a signal?

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf, erfinv
def gaussian_frequency(array_length = 10000, central_freq = 100, std = 10):
    n = np.arange(array_length)
    f = np.sqrt(2)*std*erfinv(2*n/array_length - erf(central_freq/np.sqrt(2)/std)) + central_freq
    return f
f = gaussian_frequency()
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, len(f))
t = np.linspace(0,100,100000)
signal = np.zeros(len(t))
for k in range(len(f)):
    signal += np.sin(phi[k] + 2*np.pi*f[k]*t)
def fourierPlt(signal, TIMESTEP = .001):
    num_samples = len(signal)
    k = np.arange(num_samples)
    Fs = 1/TIMESTEP
    T = num_samples/Fs
    frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
    frq = frq[range(int(num_samples/2))] # one side frequency range
    fourier = np.fft.fft(signal)/num_samples # fft computing and normalization
    fourier = abs(fourier[range(int(num_samples/2))])
    fourier = fourier/sum(fourier)
    plt.plot(frq, fourier, 'r', linewidth = 1)
    plt.title("Fast Fourier Transform")
    plt.xlabel('$f$/Hz')
    plt.ylabel('Normalized Spectrum')
    return(frq, fourier)
fourierPlt(signal)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your signal to be real-valued, you need to mirror the frequency component: you need the positive and negative frequencies to be complex conjugates of each other. I presume you thought of this.

A Gaussian-shaped frequency spectrum (with mean at *f*=0) yields a Gaussian-shaped signal.

Shifting the frequency spectrum by a frequency *f*<sub>0</sub> causes the time-domain signal to be multiplied by exp(j 2 π *f*<sub>0</sub> *t*). That is, you only change its phase.

Assuming you still want a real-valued time signal, you'll have to duplicate the frequency spectrum and shift it in both directions. This causes a multiplication by

exp(j 2 π *f*<sub>0</sub> *t*)+exp(-j 2 π *f*<sub>0</sub> *t*) = 2 cos(2 π *f*<sub>0</sub> *t*) .

Thus, your signal is a Gaussian modulating a cosine.

I'm using MATLAB here for the example, I hope you can easily translate this to Python:

```matlab
t=0:300;
s=exp(-(t-150).^2/30.^2) .* cos(2*pi*0.1*t);
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,s)
xlabel('time')

S=abs(fftshift(fft(s)));
f=linspace(-0.5,0.5,length(S));
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(f,S)
xlabel('frequency')
```

[image: code output]

For those interested in image processing: the [Gabor filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter) is exactly this, but with the frequency spectrum shifted only one direction. The resulting filter is complex, the magnitude of the filtering result is used. This leads to a phase-independent filter.